# Functional tests in android. How to wait for fragment result?

Tags: android, testing, handler

I'm trying to add test to a quite big android project. So, I'm able to add the test, both to activity both to fragments, and get they run correctly. 
But in my case, most of the fragments, when started, starts a Runnable into a new Thread. This thread connect to APIs, request and parse data, and return them to a handler, in the calling fragment.
The question is: How am I supposed to ask the test to wait until the data are retrieved by handler, so I can check them values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about instead of waiting for the values to return from real objects. You create mock objects that can return whatever value want instantly. Mockito is a great mocking framework that is very easy to use on Android.

http://code.google.com/p/mockito/

The way you go about using it is to create mock objects as opposed to real objects and you have to find "seams" to insert them into your tests. With a mock object, you can get it to return whatever value you want for any of its methods. With a mock object you can isolate dependencies. Therefore, in your example, you may want to create mock objects that mock the object that is connecting to the api because then you can return whatever value your tests need for the server to return to test whichever part of your app that you are testing. For example, if your testing whether the signUp activity is opened if the server returns that the user has entered a wrong password, you create a mock object that will return false to your activity and then insert that into where the real object is supposed to be.

Most people have issues testing existing code (that was not built with testability in mind) because there usually aren't any seams to insert test objects. Check out this awesome blog about how to make code more testable. It is contains really great advice.

http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/08/by-miko-hevery-so-you-decided-to.html

Comment: ...I've not think about this. You're totally right, I'm going to try!

Comment: It seems a very good library, but I'm not really able to understand the advantages of useing it. What's the difference from create my objects manually?!